# symfony 3 map one entity to another in different entity managers

Tags: php, symfony

I got a Symfony project with 2 databases, hence 2 entity managers and 2 different bundles (AppBundle and CommonBUndle). Config.yml is as follows:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            auto_mapping:     true
            naming_strategy:  doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        common:
            connection:       common_data
            auto_mapping:     false
            mappings:
                CommonBundle:     ~
            naming_strategy:  doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

There are 2 entities: TestPhrase (in AppBundle) and IntentSubject (in CommonBUndle).

TestPhrase.php Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use CommonBundle\Entity\IntentSubject;

/**
* TestPhrase
*
* @ORM\Table(name="test_phrase", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="KJHWJELKFH", columns={"phraseset_id"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class TestPhrase
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \CommonBundle\Entity\IntentSubject
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CommonBundle\Entity\IntentSubject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="definedsubject", referencedColumnName="rowId")
 * })
 */
private $definedsubject;
```

IntentSubject.php Entity:

```
<?php

namespace CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * IntentSubject
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Intent_subject", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="RGKJSDFHGSFG", columns={"Intent_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class IntentSubject
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="row_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $rowId;
```

So I need to get data from `CommonBundle:IntentSubject` entity when referring to `AppBundle:TestPhrase` entity but I keep getting `Unknown Entity namespace alias 'CommonBundle'` error. I tried to play with mappings in `config.yml` but it did not work. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are trying to associate entities across entity managers?  That won't work.  Entity managers are independent of each other.

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying to do.Can I write a `JOIN` statement and map the data this way?

Comment: Not really.  You can use one entity manager and use database_name.table_name in your IntentSubject but that in turn causes plenty of other problems and limitations.  Probably need to rethink your approach.